problema con python .m build
Estoy desarrollando un paquete de python puedo ejecutar python -m build y crea el .whl y .tar.gz. Cuando intento subirlo a twine python3 -m twine upload --repository pypi dist/* obtengo el siguiente error:

ERROR    InvalidDistribution: Metadata is
missing required fields: Name,
Version.
Make sure the distribution
includes the files where those
fields are specified, and is
using a supported
Metadata-Version: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2,
2.0, 2.1, 2.2.

Este es una parte del archivo pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "metodos_numericos_dcb_fi"
version = "0.1.9"

Antes si lo podia subir ya llevaba 8 versiones publicadas pero no se que cambio que no lo puedo publicar.

te recomiendo que te guíes de un proyecto que tenga actualización de no más de unos meses.
mira por ejemplo este:
https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/
descarga el código y revisa el archivo setup.py.
al día de hoy el proyecto fue publicado el 5 mar 2024, por tanto está al día.
Te dejo este ejemplo que publiqué esta misma semana:
setup.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

COMPANY_NAME="XXX"
PACKAGE_NAME = "xxx"
VERSION = "a.b.c"

install_requires = ["pydantic >=1.8","pytz >=2022.1"]
install_requires_check_1 = ["fastapi>=0.96.0","aiohttp>=3.8.5"]
install_requires_check_2 = ["fastapi>=0.96.0","starlette>=0.24.0"]

extras_require = {
    "check_1": install_requires + install_requires_check_1,
    "check_2": install_requires + install_requires_check_2,
    "check_1-check_2": install_requires + install_requires_check_1 + install_requires_check_2,
}

setup(
    name=PACKAGE_NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    description=f'This package name is reserved by {COMPANY_NAME} company',
    long_description=open('README.md', 'r').read(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    license='MIT License',
    author='xxx,
    author_email='xxx@xxx.com',
    url='https://github.com/xxx/xxx',
    keywords="api result, result dto, result scheme",
    classifiers=[
    "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
    "Environment :: Web Environment",
    "Framework :: Pydantic :: 1",
    "Framework :: Pydantic",
    "Intended Audience :: Developers",
    "Intended Audience :: Information Technology",
    "Intended Audience :: System Administrators",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: HTTP Servers",
    "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP",
    "Topic :: Internet",
    "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Application Frameworks",
    "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
    "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries",
    "Topic :: Software Development",
    "Typing :: Typed",
    ],
    packages=find_packages(),
    python_requires=">=3.8",
    install_requires=install_requires,
    extras_require=extras_require,
)




Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
